# Inverse Laplace transformation

Tags: laplace-transform

I was studying Laplace transformation with handout from my prof which states

$ \displaystyle L^{-1} [\frac {2} {s+1}] = 2te^{-t}$

However no matter how many times I try I do not get $\displaystyle L[2te^{-t}](s)=\frac {2} {s+1}$ and I guess it is supposed to be

$ \displaystyle L^{-1} [\frac {2} {s+1}] = 2e^{-t}$.

Is my answer wrong or is this just prof's typo?

If the original answer is correct, could you show how I can derive $\displaystyle L[2te^{-t}](s)=\frac {2} {s+1}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the professor's typo.  The function $2te^{-t}$ has a Laplace transform $\frac{2}{(s+1)^2}$

Comment: Thank you for answer! It is really tiring to study something from a material with this kind of typo... Anyway thank you very much!

Comment: No problem, glad to clear it up.  In the prof's defense, it seems like a pretty easy typo to make.  Feel free to upvote/accept the answer if you like it.